# How to properly set a new value for a variable into a javascript class

Tags: javascript

I would like to check the value of a variable inside my requestAnimationFrame function.
I implement this value on the scroll wheel event. It seems to work but when I check the value inside my RAF fonction, it's still set at its first value.

I wonder how can I properly set my this.deltaY value ? Thank you very much

```
class MyClass
{
    constructor ()
    {   
        this.deltaY = 0;
    }

    init ()
    {
        this.playRAF();
        window.addEventListener('wheel', function(e) {
            this.deltaY = e.deltaY;

            console.log(this.deltaY); 
            // it returns a number
        });

    }

    playRAF ()
    {
        this.leRaf = requestAnimationFrame(this.playRAF.bind(this));
        
        console.log(this.deltaY); 
        // it returns 0 all the time despite the function above :(
    }
}

//////

const foo = new MyClass();
foo.init();
```

Comment: Use an arrow function here: `window.addEventListener('wheel', e => {}`

Comment: @adiga, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, this issue is not related to what's inside my event listener but it's related on the value inside my playRAF function. Plus I don't want to use self since I will have several instances of my class.

Comment: Your event listener is definetely an issue. Without an arrow function, it will not  set `this.deltaY = e.deltaY` to the instance. Since you have a `this.playRAF()` outside, I'm assuming `init` is called on the instance of the class.

Comment: Also, you probably need to call `this.playRAF()` INSIDE the event listener if you want that called every time `wheel` event occurs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. playRAF() is a request animation frame function. So it is called all the time as soon as it is first call it. Yes I call my init() function with my instance. Since I changed my addEventListener with the arrow, my console.log(this.deltaY) returns "undefined", it seems it's not accessible anymore.

Comment: The accepted answer suggested exactly what I mentioned. What changed?

Comment: I had another function that blocked the previous fix. When I removed it your solution worked. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### This is an `this` issue

pay attention to this block, in the event listener callback, `this` is window, instead of the class instance as you thougt it is.

```js
window.addEventListener('wheel', function(e) {
  this.deltaY = e.deltaY;

  console.log(this.deltaY); 
  // it returns a number
});
```

try to check the value `window.deltaY`, you will find that it's your logged number, or try a breakpoint debugging, the `this` in the `function(e){}` is `Window` object.

turn it into

```
window.addEventListener('wheel',(e) => {
  this.deltaY = e.deltaY;

  console.log(this.deltaY); 
  // it returns a number
});
```

will solve this problem, as the arrow will not create a function block, `this` will be the class instance as expected.